# NextJS: unable to set title with dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am not able to set title and others meta tags on a page created with dynamic routes.
Title and metas are set correctly when the page is loaded in the browser, but they are not set in the raw HTML code I fetch using wget.

I have tried using both `<Head>` and `<NextSeo>` with same results.
I have also tried both `getStaticProps() / getStaticPaths()` and `getServerSideProps()` approaches.

Here is a simplified snippet of my code.

```js
const PostPage = ( { post } ) => {
    let txt = post.text || post.brief_descr;


    return (
        <Layout>
            <NextSeo
                title={post.title}
                description={post.brief_descr}
            />
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </Layout>
    );
};


export async function getServerSideProps ( { res, query } ) {
    const p = query.params[ 0 ];

    const data = await act_post_get( id, slug )();

    return {
        props: { post: data }
    };

}
```

Comment: What does your `Layout` component look like?

Comment: Hello @juliomalves   it was not the `Layout` component the culprit, but my `_document.tsx` file with a wrong `getInitialProps()`. Now it works.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was messing things up with the `_document.tsx` and the `getInitialProps()` function.
By simplifying the `_document.tsx` I was able to use the `getStaticProps()` with `revalidate` option correctly, and now it works as expected.